# Is there a way for Bazaar to automatically detect and apply changes made in a working directory?

Tags: bazaar

Is there a way for Bazaar to be able to automatically detect changes (adds, removes, renames, etc.) made to part of the working directory and automatically apply them?

I have a directory tree in my repository which is generated by another process so  I can't do all the `bzr add`, `bzr delete`, and `bzr rename` commands as the files are changing.  Instead, I would like a way to have bzr notice all the changes and apply them after this process is run.

The only way I can think of doing this right now is running `bzr status` and then manually (or by writing a script) run `bzr add` and `bzr delete` on all the files listed.  This will work but I am hoping there is an automated method that could also determine if a file was renamed (an added file has the same contents of a delete file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly mark files as deleted. And bzr can detect renames (either with automv plugin or with builtin functionality):

```
bzr mv --auto
```

Note that if you moved the files to a new folder that you just created, you have to version it, but without adding its children (`--no-recurse`), othervise `mv --auto` might fail to detect renames:

```
bzr add --no-recurse newfolder
```

Then you need to add all files which are not part of renames:

```
bzr add subdir/
```

Comment: Do you know what differences (if any) there are between `bzr mv --auto` and the automv plugin?

Comment: automv plugin allows you to specify the similarity level between files with --threshold. Both have --dry-run to check heuristics before record actual renames. mv --auto is builtin, so you don't need to bother to install additional plugins, vanilla bzr will be enough. Historically automv was born first. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just call `bzr add *` at the end of the process? Your subsequent commit should take care of all additions and removals. This will not detect if a file was renamed/moved by some process other than `bzr mv` (and I am unaware of any way to do so).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [automv](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/automv-plugin.html) plug-in will automatically detect renames and moves.  This, along with `bzr add *` should do the trick.